# Using ReactTestUtils in a browser console

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to setup some automation using the ReactTestUtils, and while I was playing around in the browser's console, I got the following errors:

Attempt 1:

```
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils
Uncaught TypeError: React.addons is undefined
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1
debugger eval code:1:17
```

Attempt 2:

```
var TestUtils = React.import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
```

According to [The Guide to Test Automation of ReactJS Apps](https://waverleysoftware.com/blog/test-automation-of-reactjs-apps/):

> To use it in the web browser and scripts of the Selenium testing framework we have to set its reference into a root window object.

How exactly can one set up a root window object in Firefox, Chrome, or Selenium WebDriver?

Another solution given [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/148) is to set `config.react.addons = true` in the config/application.rb, but I'm not sure that's available in a Python-Dash project. I've also installed [an extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/react-devtools/), but it looks like something related to profiling. Thanks in advance for any insight!